# Print an array with ng-repeat that doesn't have field name.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array that is like this:

```
{"platillos":{"columns":["id_platillo","codigo"],"records":[["1","HAMB01"]]}}
```

so i put `ng-repeat="dish in platillos"` on the row and when i want to print on html i have:

```
{{dish.id_platillo}}
```

But it doesn't appear on the web page.

how do i access to that record of the object?

this is how i see it on the console -> [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FMFq.jpg)

i have a 15 there, here i only put 2 fields to demonstrate my issue.

Thanks!

Comment: {{dish.records[0]}}  will get you the id

Comment: @ZetCoby it show me all the array that is on the records[0], so it doesn't show me only the id

Comment: oh there are 2 arrays now i see, try {{dish.records[0][0]}}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop over the records then:

```
ng-repeat="dish in objectName.platillos.records"
```

And if you want to loop over the columns then:

```
ng-repeat="dish in objectName.platillos.columns"
```

Because platillos is a key with 2 objects inside (columns and platillos) and inside each key you can find the array.

Comment: And how do i find an specific value inside the array to print it. {{dish.??}}

Comment: If you want a value inside the array then you have to print dish[X] (if you want the id, then it's dish[0]) because it's an array and you have to use [X] to access an element of an array, where X is the position.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the first response. Platillos is also a key, so you have to include it. objectName is the whole javascript object, so it's the variable where you have stored the json

Comment: On objectName what should I put, or that is the name of a predefined variable ?

Comment: Exactly, the name of your variable

Comment: @GabrielSantana if the answer worked for you I would appreciate a +1 and mark the answer as the correct one. Thanks!